# How to reduce the size of the ViewModel in C# WPF using classes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

Following on from a previous question I posted last week, I have a Chart/Graph application in which I aim to read data from three sensors and plot it.

I will be able to do this without too much difficulty but previously I had not followed MVVM principles as I was new to WPF and had absolutely everything in the code behind. Now I am in the process of rewriting my Chart/Graph app using MVVM.

The difficulty I am having is trying to split up the MainWindowViewModel to handle stuff elsewhere in other classes to avoid the class being long and complex.

I have the following:

**MODEL**

```
public class MainWindowModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SensorDataModel1> ocSensor1{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SensorDataModel2> ocSensor2{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SensorDataModel3> ocSensor3{ get; set; }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public ObservableCollection<Sensor1DataModel> ocSensor1Data
    {
        get { return _model.ocSensor1; }
        set
        {
            _model.ocSensor1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ocSensor1Data");
        }
    }

    private void SerialDataReceivedHandler(object sender, 
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // parse all sensor data from Arduino to a list
        List<string> arduinoData = e.ToString().Split(',').ToList();

        // parses data here into 3 variables

        // sends to each sensors class (pseudocode to simplify example)
        sensor1Class.AddData(data1);
        sensor2Class.AddData(data2);
        sensor3Class.AddData(data3);
    }
}
```

**Sensor Class Example**

```
// Does some conversions to the data and then updates the ObservableCollection 
// in the MainWindowViewModel
public class Sensor1Class
{
        MainWindowViewModel main;
        public Sensor1Class()
        {
            main = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }

                public void AddData(List<string> data)
        {
            SensorDataModel1 model = new SensorDataModel1();

            // does some stuff to the data here

            // add parsed data to observable collection in viewmodel to be used by UI
            main.ocSensor1Data.Add(model);
        }
}
```

So here I have a basic MVVM architecture, I have a Sensor1/2/3Class to reduce some work in the MainWindowViewModel where it needs to do some conversions for the data that's read in.

Ideally I would like to have my own Axis, Label, LineSeries, ChartZoom etc. classes to take a lot of code out of the MainWindowViewModel.

Example: Have an **Axis.cs** class to hold axis specific data

```
public class Axis
{
    // TODO - Axis class
    private double AxisMin;
    private double AxisMax;


    #region setters
    public void SetAxisLimits(double min, double max)
    {
        AxisMin = min;
        AxisMax = max;
    }

    public void SetAxisMin(double value)
    {
        AxisMin = value;
    }

    public void SetAxisMax(double value)
    {
        AxisMax = value;
    }
    #endregion

    #region getters
    public double GetAxisMin()
    {
        return AxisMin;
    }

    public double GetAxisMax()
    {
        return AxisMax;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So instead of all this being in the MainWindowViewModel I can hold it here, however would I need to create a separate Model & ViewModel for Axis, LineSeries, Label and so on and set the DataContext to each individually to have something like this?

I am basically trying to combine MVVM with more OO principles, but then I may be violating MVVM altogether by doing this. I want to know what the best way is to structure my application with a lot of classes and still update the same view.

Comment: Your restructuring looks good to me.  Just have one top-level aggregation viewmodel that exposes each of the sub-viewmodels and then set the `DataContext` appropriately for each in the view

Comment: The view model may expose a property that return an `Axis` for example. You can then bind to this property and any other nested property in the view: `{Binding Axis.SomeProperty}`.

Comment: The same principles apply to mvvm as usual. You should be following SOLID and DRY so long as they are practical and useful. A class should only have one reason to change ideally. Dependencies should be injected via constructor. Inheritance can save repeated code.  With SOLID, if you're splitting things down and that creates problems then that's the point to reconsider whether what you're doing is a plus or a minus.